# Why is my react app rendering two input check boxes on mobile? Looks fine on desktop. (See Photos)

Tags: css, reactjs, mobile, jsx, react-bootstrap

Not sure what other info I could supply besides one of the columns that would be helpful. I'm stumped.

[edit] Added full code for this component. This looks fine on desktop but not on my phone or tablet. See the photos. I'm repeating this because I can't save my edits to this question due to having too much code and not enough information so here I am rambling about nothing.

Mobile:

[image: mobile]

Desktop:

[image: desktop]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import API from '../utils/API';

class Attendance extends Component {
    state = {
        selectedOption: "",
        disabled: ""
    };

    handleOptionChange = (changeEvent) => {
        this.setState({
            selectedOption: changeEvent.target.value
        });
    };

    handleFormSubmit = (formSubmitEvent) => {
        formSubmitEvent.preventDefault();

        if (!this.state.selectedOption) {
            return;
        } else {
            this.setState({
                disabled: "true"
            })
            API.updateAttendance(this.props.student._id, { present: this.state.selectedOption });
        }
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="col d-flex justify-content-end" >
                <form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>

                    <div className="row mt-3">

                        <div className="col-sm-3">
                            <label className="text-danger">
                                <input
                                    type="checkbox"
                                    value="absent"
                                    checked={this.state.selectedOption === 'absent'}
                                    onChange={this.handleOptionChange}
                                    disabled={this.state.disabled}
                                />
                                Absent
                            </label>
                        </div>

                        <div className="col-sm-3">
                            <label className="text-warning">
                                <input
                                    type="checkbox"
                                    value="excused"
                                    checked={this.state.selectedOption === 'excused'}
                                    onChange={this.handleOptionChange}
                                    disabled={this.state.disabled}
                                />
                                Excused
                            </label>
                        </div>

                        <div className="col-sm-3">
                            <label className="text-success">
                                <input
                                    type="checkbox"
                                    value="present"
                                    checked={this.state.selectedOption === 'present'}
                                    onChange={this.handleOptionChange}
                                    disabled={this.state.disabled}
                                />
                                Present
                            </label>
                        </div>

                        <div className="col-sm-3">
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-sm btn-dark" onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit} disabled={this.state.disabled}>
                                    <i className="fas fa-user-check" />
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Attendance;
```

Comment: Its seems you have a custom style for checkbox, please add complete code

Comment: @Alex I added the complete code for the component.